# 'typeparam' syntax error in razor components - blazor

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, blazor, razor-components

have this razor generic component `TModel` with parameters of `Expression<Func<TModel,object>>[]` parameter
now when the parent component of the previous one gives `TModel` type `WorkOrder`
the `Expression<Func<TModel,object>>` remains `TModel` and therefore I can't pass `WorkOrder` expressions!

***Code***

**DataGridComponent.razor.cs**

```
public partial class DataGridComponent<TModel> : ComponentBase , IDisposable
    where TModel : DbModel
    {
        [Parameter]
        public Expression<Func<TModel, object>>[] Properties { get; set; }
}
```

**SomeViewModel.razor**

```
<div>
<DataGridComponent TModel="WorkOrder" Orderable="true" Indexable="true" 
Properties="new Expression<Func<WorkOrder, object>>[] {    <--------- Syntax Error
                                                                    a=>a.Location.LocationType,
                                                                    a=>a.MainService
                                                                }"></DataGridComponent>
</div>
```

and it shows the conversion regular syntax error

> Cannot covert Expression.... WorkOrder to ... TModel

Further technical details

- ASP.NET Core version : 3.1
- The IDE (VS 16.4 prev. 4)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it worked fine if it is List<> but not array...
this is a workaround i guess :)